# Extend “reduceRegions” function application for more the 5000 elements in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Does anyone knows if is it possible to extend “reduceRegions” funtion application of GEE for more than 5000 elements?

I think it is by default limited to 5000 points/polygons in a feature collections, when I call it as following:

```
var Xfeatures_sum = ImageX.reduceRegions({
  collection: Xfeatures,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The 5000 limit is for things you print.  If you want more, [export the result](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting#exporting-tables-and-vector-data).

Comment: Hi, I got this error mgs "Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements"  when I've tried to use 'reduceRegions' funtion for a feature collection with more than 5000 points. Maybe I need to split it then.
Thank you!

Comment: You simply can't print or chart more than 5000 things.